# Which of the statements is not necessarily true?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions, generalized-eigenvector

Let $A$ be a $3\times3$ matrix and $u, v, w$ be linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that:

$Au = 2u, Av = 2v, Aw = 0$.

Which of the statements are **NOT** necessarily true?

Option 1: $w$ is an eigenvector of $A$.

Option 2: $\text{span}({u,v})$ is the eigenspace of $A$ associated with eigenvalue 2.

Option 3: $u+w$ is an eigenvector of $A$ associated with eigenvalue 2.

Option 4: $2u$ is an eigenvector of $A$ associated with eigenvalue 2.

Option 5: All the statements are necessarily true.

I am not sure about option 2 and 3, but I think option 1 and 4 are true. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 1):

Option 2 is certainly the most difficult. What do you know about the total sum of the geometric multiplicities of eigenvalues?

We know that $\text{span}(u, v)$ is at least a subset of the eigenspace of 2, so the geometric multiplicity of 2 is at least 2.

Assume that $\text{span}(u, v)$ is not all of the eigenspace of 2, then the geometric multiplicity of 2 is at least 3. But we know that $w$ is an eigenvector for 0, showing that the geometric multiplicity is at least 1. Is it possible for the geometric multiplicity of 2 to be at least 3 and that of 0 to be at least 1?

Option 3 is asking you whether $u+w$ is a nonzero vector that satisfies $A(u+w)=2(u+w)$. Is it?